# Modifying Dalvik Virtual Machine to intercept methods of Application code

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik

In my current implementation, I can only intercept the Method_Entry event of the some Class initialization methods, including:

```
*.<init> or *.<cinit>
* stands for any Class
```

All the methods written in Java applications are missing.

Currently, I have inserted "fprintf()" in the following places:

```
stack.cpp: dvmCallMethod() 
stack.cpp: dvmCallMethodV() 
stack.cpp: dvmCallMethodA()
stack.cpp: dvmInvokeMethod()
Interp.cpp: dvmInterpret()
Mterp.cpp: dvmMterpStd()
```

When these places of DVM are executed, I will print a message in my log file. However, only the Class initialization functions has triggered my println() code. In other words, it looks like that the execution of application methods does not go through the above places of DVM. I don't know which part of DVM is responsible for method execution of applications. Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: Please try to format your question, this is hard to read.

Comment: I just re-edited. you can see it now.Can you help me?

Comment: Please don't interact with this question unless you are *actually prepared to help* someone **who is attempting to make modifications deep inside the implementation of the VM**.  If that is not you, then *you are not the audience* and unlikely to understand the issue here.

Comment: I want to know the which function is execute application opcode. Now I modify some cpp to know which one

Comment: My code is not be skipped. I compiled dalvik to libdvm.so , and disassembling it in IDA, My code is still there. Even I debugged it.

Comment: I know your meaning. android has three execute-mode: JIT, fast, portable.I tested all three modes even the portable. I read the handbook, the portable not pre-compile the opcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to figure out how things work is to look at how the method profiling works.  Profiling adds an entry to a log file every time a method is called.  The key file is [dalvik/vm/Profile.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/Profile.h), which defines macros like `TRACE_METHOD_ENTER`.  (In gingerbread, this was all you needed to look for. The situation changed quite a bit in ICS, when the interaction between debugging, profiling, and JIT compilation got reworked.  And KitKat added the "sampling" profiler into the mix. So it's a bit more twisty now, and there are some other functions to be aware of, like `dvmFastMethodTraceEnter()`.)

The entry points you've identified in your question are for reflection and calls in and out of native code.  Calls between interpreted code are handled by updating the stack and program counter, and just continuing to loop through the interpreter. You can see this at [line 3928 in the portable interpreter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-portable.cpp#3928).

The non-obvious part is the `FINISH()` macro, defined on line 415. This calls into `dvmCheckBefore()`, line [1692 in Interp.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/interp/Interp.cpp#1692). This function checks the `subMode` field to see if there is anything interesting to do; you can find the various meanings in the definition, [line 50 in InterpState.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/interp/InterpState.h#50).  In short, flags are used for various profiling, debugging, and JIT compilation features.

You can see a `subMode` check on [line 3916 in the portable interpreter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-portable.cpp#3916), in the method invocation handling. It calls into `dvmReportInvoke()`, over in [Interp.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/interp/Interp.cpp#640), which invokes the `TRACE_METHOD_ENTER` macro.

If you're just trying to have something happen every time any method is invoked, you should probably just wire it into the profiling system, as that's already doing what you want.  If you don't need the method profiling features, just replace them with your code.

Comment: I added my log function in:GOTO_TARGET(invokeMethod, bool methodCallRange, const Method* _methodToCall,
3793    u2 count, u2 regs) ,within InterpC-portable.cpp. The application code is executed.But I still don't understand why application codes are running here.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're not understanding. The `invokeMethod` goto target has the common code for method invocation handling. It either calls into a native method, or moves the PC to the start of the called method and continues to loop through instructions.

Comment: The big loop is starting by <init> or <cinit> method, it doesnt't relative with application codes, and <init> or <cinit> method does not invoke application method , why can application codes execute?

Comment: The VM code is structured as a shared library, so execution begins when somebody -- usually the app framework -- makes a JNI call. Take a look at the sources for the command-line `dalvikvm` to see what I mean: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/jb-mr2-release/dalvikvm/Main.cpp .  The `CallStaticVoidMethod()` on line 273 is where interpreted code execution begins (if you ignore class loader activity). Follow that through Jni.cpp (`CallStatic##_jname##Method`) to `dvmCallMethodV()` in interp/Stack.cpp, which calls `dvmInterpret()`.

Comment: FWIW, the place where the Android app framework first starts executing interpreted code is in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/jni/AndroidRuntime.cpp#798 .

Comment: Your answer is absolutly help me. Thanks.Application codes execute starting by system odex such as:framework.odex. This suitation puzzles me. Even few application codes execute starting by itself, invoking other function only modifies the PC, it's still in the same big loop.(I thought it would invoke enter into a new loop ago)